# How to test if my ServerSpec command condition written in Ruby works?

Tags: ruby, serverspec

I'm using the following ruby script

```
describe command('curl -s -k - i %{http_code} https://localhost/xx/xxx') do
  its(:stdout) { should match /200/ }
end
```

But I'm unsure if this script works or not. How can I make sure this script works?

Comment: run it via `bundle exec rspec path/to/the/file_spec.rb`

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the reply. But I'm sorry not to mention this in the question. I want to know whether the curl command gives the http code. In the meanwhile, I'll be running the script as you suggested.!

Answer (score 1):

Generally Serverspec is used with Chef via the Test Kitchen integration testing framework (though these days InSpec is more popular). You run your tests using the `kitchen verify` command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you want is:

```
describe command('curl -s -k -I https://localhost/xx/xxx') do
  its(:stdout) { should match /200/ }
end
```